# Creating static file on postPersist and postUpdate Entity in Symfony2

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, menu, symfony-2.3

I want to create a static twig file whenever a operation like persist or update  will be done in Admin. What i am thinking is to create a listener called GenerateStaticListener. The listener will listen  the events postPersist or postUpdate and called the custom function. The Custom function will fetch the item from database and write it into the html file and then i will include the twig file(html file ) into my layout. The purpose for this is to generate a html file (i.e twig) once so that to fetch the item from database query will not hit again  and again on database and give better performance.

**Scenario:**

The Menu section of my site contain lots of items.And fetching will be done from more than one table and around 10 queries will be fired to fetch the items. Limitation will be  lack of page performance and user experience. The Menu Section is just like mashable.com

I just want to know from you guys that which is the right approach.
Any other approach???

Answer (score 1):

In this context, use listeners is good solution to do that work.

But create static file isn't the best way to do. You will have some problem like write access, location etc...

Have you look after cache system ? Like varnish for file cache or memcached for stock your data into RAM.

You can check this bundle for Sf2 [LeaseWeb/Memcached](https://github.com/LeaseWeb/LswMemcacheBundle)

With this, your controller will get data from RAM and not from disk (BDD), that is 10x faster or more.